# Check AVPlayer buffering and playing state

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer

I want to know that how i can check that `AVPlayer` is not playing music when i click on play Button(`player.play()`) and it currently (buffering or loading) due to slow internet connection or due to other causes, and also check when it play music after buffering.
Because i need to add `UIActivityIndicatorView` on Play button. When Play button is clicked it animate till the buffering and when AVPlayer play song after buffering it stop animating and when it `AVPlayer` again start buffering it again animate.
Can anyone please tell me how i can do this with simple way like this

```
if (player is buffering){
    activityIndicator.tartAnimating()
}else if player is playing music{
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

and also check again and again using `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self, selector: "check", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

Or any other simple solution?
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51302214/3887987

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems similar to a question I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42148482/5100819

The approach we used to update the UI when the AVPlayer finishes buffering and starts actual audible playback would likely do the job. We used a boundary time to execute a block at the start of playback – specifically after 1/3 of a second of playback – to update the UI at roughly the same time as audio is heard:

```
let times = [NSValue(time:CMTimeMake(1,3))]
_ = self.player.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: times, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: {
    [weak self] time in
    // Code to update the UI goes here, e.g.
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
})
```

I have a little more detail on the approach (and a sample Xcode project) on our company blog: http://www.artermobilize.com/blog/2017/02/09/detect-when-ios-avplayer-finishes-buffering-using-swift/