# How can I check if my AVPlayer is buffering?

Tags: ios, avplayer, buffering

I want to detect if my AVPlayer is buffering for the current location, so that I can show a loader or something. But I can't seem to find anything in the documentation for AVPlayer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can observe the values of your `player.currentItem`:

```
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: .New, context: nil)
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: .New, context: nil)
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull", options: .New, context: nil)
```

then

```
override public func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if object is AVPlayerItem {
        switch keyPath {
            case "playbackBufferEmpty":
               // Show loader

            case "playbackLikelyToKeepUp":
                // Hide loader

            case "playbackBufferFull":
                // Hide loader
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When AVPlayer is seeking to certain position, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Marco_Santarossa I've used the above code and it is working. But after view controller is popOut the code is crashing can you help me with this.

Comment: Hey @ArunK. Are you removing the observer when you dismiss your view ? Make also sure you're stopping and destroying all the objects before removing the view otherwise you might have some memory leaks. I would need an example of your code to understand if this is the case

Comment: "playbackBufferFull" is never being called in my case. Can you plz suggest me the reason? @Marco

Comment: @FrankCheng try setting the observation options to 0 instead of .new

Comment: @PatrickCary how to check buffer status if avPlayer has just seeked to a specific position?

Comment: Code crashing all the time.

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, I used the code below to show the loader efficiently.

> Swift 3

```
//properties 
var observer:Any!
var player:AVPlayer!


self.observer = self.player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMake(1, 600), queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    [weak self] time in

    if self?.player.currentItem?.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay {

        if let isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp = self?.player.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
            //do what ever you want with isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp value, for example, show or hide a activity indicator.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @aytek, would you please be so kind and translate your solution to `Swift 4`? :)

Comment: Dear @ixany, I didn't have a chance to install the latest build of Xcode. I'll add the Swift 4 version as soon as possible. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What I have observed is that you have to register to those observers on the AVPlayerItem instance and not the AVPlayer's one, otherwise it doesn't work. In fact, the accepted answer does that.

Answer (score 19):

For me above accepted answer didn't worked but this method does.You can use timeControlStatus but it is available only above iOS 10.

According to apple's official documentation

> A status that indicates whether playback is currently in progress,
>   paused indefinitely, or suspended while waiting for appropriate
>   network conditions

Add this observer to the player.

```
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: “timeControlStatus”, options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
```

Then,Observe the changes in

```
func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

method.Use below code inside above method

```
override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "timeControlStatus", let change = change, let newValue = change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? Int, let oldValue = change[NSKeyValueChangeKey.oldKey] as? Int {
        let oldStatus = AVPlayer.TimeControlStatus(rawValue: oldValue)
        let newStatus = AVPlayer.TimeControlStatus(rawValue: newValue)
        if newStatus != oldStatus {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
                if newStatus == .playing || newStatus == .paused {
                    self?.loaderView.isHidden = true
                } else {
                    self?.loaderView.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is tested on iOS 11 above with swift 4 and It is working.

Comment: this is the only thing that works on iOS 13 and swift 5

Answer (score 8):

**#Updated in Swift 4 and worked fine**

As through i have gone with accepted answer but didn't work in **swift 4** for me so after certain research i have found [this thinks from apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserver). There are two way to determine **AVPlayer states** that are,

1. addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock: and
2. addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes:queue:usingBlock:

and using ways is like this

```
var observer:Any?
var avplayer : AVPlayer?

func preriodicTimeObsever(){

        if let observer = self.observer{
            //removing time obse
            avplayer?.removeTimeObserver(observer)
            observer = nil
        }

        let intervel : CMTime = CMTimeMake(1, 10)
        observer = avplayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: intervel, queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] time in

            guard let `self` = self else { return }

            let sliderValue : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
           //this is the slider value update if you are using UISlider.

            let playbackLikelyToKeepUp = self.avPlayer?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp
            if playbackLikelyToKeepUp == false{

               //Here start the activity indicator inorder to show buffering
            }else{
                //stop the activity indicator 
            }
        }
    }
```

**And Don't forget to kill time observer to save from memory leak**. method for killing instance, add this method according to your need but i have used it in viewWillDisappear method.

```
       if let observer = self.observer{

            self.avPlayer?.removeTimeObserver(observer)
            observer = nil
        }
```

Comment: Amrit Tiwari, why do you use strong link?

Comment: in addPeriodicTimeObserver we have to used weak reference so I am wrapping self to used self properties!!!

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4 observations:

```
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
var playbackLikelyToKeepUpKeyPathObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
var playbackBufferEmptyObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
var playbackBufferFullObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

private func observeBuffering() {
    let playbackBufferEmptyKeyPath = \AVPlayerItem.playbackBufferEmpty
    playbackBufferEmptyObserver = playerItem?.observe(playbackBufferEmptyKeyPath, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (_, _) in
        // show buffering
    }

    let playbackLikelyToKeepUpKeyPath = \AVPlayerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp
    playbackLikelyToKeepUpKeyPathObserver = playerItem?.observe(playbackLikelyToKeepUpKeyPath, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (_, _) in
        // hide buffering
    }

    let playbackBufferFullKeyPath = \AVPlayerItem.playbackBufferFull
    playbackBufferFullObserver = playerItem?.observe(playbackBufferFullKeyPath, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (_, _) in
        // hide buffering
    }
}
```

Observers need to be removed after we are done observing.

To remove these three observers just set `playbackBufferEmptyObserver`, `playbackLikelyToKeepUpKeyPathObserver` and `playbackBufferFullObserver` to `nil`.

No need to remove them manually (this is specific for `observe<Value>(_ keyPath:, options:, changeHandler:)` method.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 5.3

Vars:

```
private var playerItemBufferEmptyObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
private var playerItemBufferKeepUpObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
private var playerItemBufferFullObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

AddObservers

```
playerItemBufferEmptyObserver = player.currentItem?.observe(\AVPlayerItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (_, _) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.showLoadingIndicator(over: self)
}
    
playerItemBufferKeepUpObserver = player.currentItem?.observe(\AVPlayerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (_, _) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.dismissLoadingIndicator()
}
    
playerItemBufferFullObserver = player.currentItem?.observe(\AVPlayerItem.isPlaybackBufferFull, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (_, _) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.dismissLoadingIndicator()
}
```

RemoveObservers

```
playerItemBufferEmptyObserver?.invalidate()
playerItemBufferEmptyObserver = nil
    
playerItemBufferKeepUpObserver?.invalidate()
playerItemBufferKeepUpObserver = nil
    
playerItemBufferFullObserver?.invalidate()
playerItemBufferFullObserver = nil
```

Comment: These observer are never trigger. Do you know why ?

Comment: Where do you declare the properties?

Comment: In init of the class that manage the AvPlayer . I call a function that init all observers then I call the call logic to create an AVPlayerItem to stream into the player. 
The observers (currentItem.status, actionItemAdded and rate) are triggering but not these.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me on iOS 16 and AVPlayer wrapped in SwiftUI's VideoPlayer. Without this, could not find a way to show an indicator. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated for Swift 4.2**

```
    var player : AVPlayer? = nil

    let videoUrl = URL(string: "https://wolverine.raywenderlich.com/content/ios/tutorials/video_streaming/foxVillage.mp4")
    self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl!)
    self.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 600), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { time in

        if self.player?.currentItem?.status == AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay {

            if let isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp = self.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
                //do what ever you want with isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp value, for example, show or hide a activity indicator.

                //MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: That worked thanks, but it's recommended to use weak self in the block. I posted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, the accepted solution didn't work for me and the periodic observer solutions seem heavy handed.

Here's my suggestion, observe `timeControlerStatus` on `AVPlayer`.

```
// Add observer
player.addObserver(self,
                   forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.timeControlStatus),
                   options: [.new],
                   context: &playerItemContext)

// At some point you'll need to remove yourself as an observer otherwise
// your app will crash 
self.player?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.timeControlStatus))

// handle keypath callback
if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayer.timeControlStatus) {
    guard let player = self.player else { return }
    if let isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp = player.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp,
        player.timeControlStatus != .playing && !isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
        self.playerControls?.loadingStatusChanged(true)
    } else {
        self.playerControls?.loadingStatusChanged(false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can directly **Observe Playback State** using the state observer method once is there any playback state changes it will be notified, it's a really easy way and it's tested with **swift 5** and **iOS 13.0+**

```
var player: AVPlayer!

player.currentItem!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: .new, context: nil)

func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                  of object: Any?,
                  change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                  contexts: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if (player.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp ?? false) {
        // End Buffering
    } else {
        // Buffering is in progress
    }
}
```

[Apple Doc Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/observing_playback_state)

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Xamarin inspired by [Marco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38867386/2304737)

```
// KVO registrations
private void Initialize()
{
    playbackBufferEmptyObserver?.Dispose();
    playbackBufferEmptyObserver = (NSObject)playerItem.AddObserver("playbackBufferEmpty",
        NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New,
        AVPlayerItem_BufferUpdated);

    playbackLikelyToKeepUpObserver?.Dispose();
    playbackLikelyToKeepUpObserver = (NSObject)playerItem.AddObserver("playbackLikelyToKeepUp",
        NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New,
        AVPlayerItem_BufferUpdated);

    playbackBufferFullObserver?.Dispose();
    playbackBufferFullObserver = (NSObject)playerItem.AddObserver("playbackBufferFull",
        NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New,
        AVPlayerItem_BufferUpdated);
}

private void AVPlayerItem_BufferUpdated(NSObservedChange e)
{
    ReportVideoBuffering();
}

private void ReportVideoBuffering()
{
    // currentPlayerItem is the current AVPlayerItem of AVPlayer
    var isBuffering = !currentPlayerItem.PlaybackLikelyToKeepUp;
    // NOTE don't make "buffering" as one of your PlayerState.
    // Treat it as a separate property instead. Learned this the hard way.
    Buffering?.Invoke(this, new BufferingEventArgs(isBuffering));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that

> Use a weak reference to self in the callback block to prevent creating a retain cycle.

```
func playRemote(url: URL) {
            showSpinner()
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
            avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            avPlayer.rate = 1.0
            avPlayer.play()
            self.avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMake(value: 1,
     timescale: 600), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [weak self] time in
                if self?.avPlayer.currentItem?.status == AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay {
                    if let isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp = self?.avPlayer.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp { 
                        self?.removeSpinner()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Combine you can easily subscribe to the publisher for when an AVPlayerItem is buffering or not like so:

```
// Subscribe to this and update your `View` appropriately
@Published var isBuffering = false
private var observation: AnyCancellable?

observation = avPlayer?.currentItem?.publisher(for: \.isPlaybackBufferEmpty).sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] isBuffering in
  self?.isBuffering = isBuffering
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For **RXswift** fans, you can check AVPlayer's buffering state by adding an extension to the `Reactive` class:

```
extension Reactive where Base: AVPlayerItem {
    public var playbackBufferEmpty: Observable<Bool> {
        return self.observe(Bool.self, #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty))
            .map { $0 ?? false }
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
   avPlayerItem.rx.playbackBufferEmpty
   .subscribe(onNext: {isLoading in

      //Do whatever you want

    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method, that works with **Swift 5**.

This will add the loadingIndicator when your player is stalled

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
#selector(playerStalled(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled, object: self.player?.currentItem)

@objc func playerStalled(_ notification: Notification){
    self.loadingIndicator.isHidden = false
    self.playPauseButton.isHidden = true
}
```

This will show loader Indicator when buffer is empty:

```
if let isPlayBackBufferEmpty = self.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackBufferEmpty{
    if isPlayBackBufferEmpty{
        self.loadingIndicator.isHidden = false
        self.playPauseButton.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

This will hide the loader when player is ready to play:

```
if self.playerItem?.status == AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay{
    if let isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp = self.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
        if isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp{
            self.loadingIndicator.isHidden = true
            self.playPauseButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for me the above notifcation is not getting called, can u please help

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the player is buffering/loading like this:

```
let playerObserver = self.player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [weak self] time in
        if self?.player.timeControlStatus == .playing {
            debugPrint("#player - info: isPlaying")
            self?.playButton.isSelected = true
        } else if self?.player.timeControlStatus == .paused {
            debugPrint("#player - info: isPaused")
            self?.playButton.isSelected = false
        } else if self?.player.timeControlStatus == .waitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate {
            debugPrint("#player - info: isWaiting") //Buffering
        }
    })
```