# Add activity indicator in AVPLayerViewController ? (Note: When video is in fullscreen mode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, development-environment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EHG8.png)How to Add activity indicator in the center of AVPLayerViewController when it is in fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code when user press play button

```
if(playerViewController.view.subviews.count != 0)
{
  UIView *AVTouchIgnoringView = playerViewController.view.subviews[0].subviews.lastObject;
  activityIndicatorBuffer.center = playerViewController.view.center;
  [AVTouchIgnoringView addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
  [AVTouchIgnoringView bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicatorView];
}
```

and Don't forget to add below methods

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [playerViewController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"videoBounds" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
     [playerViewController removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"videoBounds"];
}
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString )keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary )change context:(void *)context
{
     if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"videoBounds"])
     {
        float height = playerViewController.contentOverlayView.bounds.size.height;
        float width = playerViewController.contentOverlayView.bounds.size.width;
        if (height == SCREEN_HEIGHT && width == SCREEN_WIDTH)
        {
            activityIndicatorBuffer.center = playerViewController.contentOverlayView.center;
        }
        else
        {
            activityIndicatorBuffer.center = playerViewController.view.center;    
        }
     }
}
```

and don't forget to start animating when buffering. click here [this link for check AVPlayer is buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867190/how-can-i-check-if-my-avplayer-is-buffering)

Comment: wel come @Wasim Makwana

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom indicator view in centre of AVPLayerViewController by adding custom view on main key window.

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(your custom indicator view)
```

You can set centre of your custom indicator view as below.

```
activity.center = CGPoint.init(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/2.0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2.0)
```

Comment: Brother I want indicator on center of AVplayerviewController when AVplayerviewController is in full screen mode

Comment: ok. can you please share screen shot so it's for me to find out how do you want it?

Comment: Ok brother I had added sc can you please refer it

Comment: Thanks for screen shot. It seems your build target is less than iOS 8. Can you please paste your code to play this video? Also can you please tell on which version of iOS you are playing this video?

Comment: I am running video in IOS 10. At time when screen is in fullscreen mode at that time i want to just display activity indicator in centre of the fullscreen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is working but when video is not in full screen at that time also indicator is displaying.Here we doesn't have fullscreen button action event as it is default.

Comment: Can you tell me that how can i get the front view in AVPlayervViewController? As because i want to add activity indicator in that view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything you add on main key window will get added on top layer.